# Is there any function like sleepWithTimeInterval() in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, time, sleep, nstimeinterval

When using Linux, there is two simple sleep function **sleep()** and **usleep()**.

But as OS X provides a useful timer data type NSTimeInterval as double, is there any simple function like **sleepWithTimeInterval()** or something to achieve the "sleep"?

If not, how should I write my own function or method to achieve that, and meanwhile **advoid complex calculation** (such as minimize float point number multiplication and division)?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

[NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Specifically,

```
scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:
```

You can also do it with GCD.

```
 dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, <A Number> * NSEC_PER_SEC);
 dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^someblockCode);
```

Comment: Oh, I read the document of NSTimer. It mentioned: "After seconds seconds have elapsed, the timer fires, invoking invocation." I do not understand what "fire" means. And NSInvocation is new to me. Now still reading it...

Comment: Looking at the example I provided and at the very minimum using it to google will give you quite a few real world examples

Comment: Seems if I use NSTimer or GCD, a block or a selector is required. And I should check some block flag variable in my main thread which call the sleepWithTimeInterval(). Am I right?

Comment: A selector is a pointer to a method. So in short, you have to point it to a method you created in your class. As for the main thread question, it doesn't have to be on the main thread, just whatever thread you want to make wait, which for most is the main thread.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point. Actually what I wanted to do is simply package a sleepWithInterval(...). But GCD and NSTimer seem not to be simply ways to achieve that. Anyway, you suggestion still helps. Thank you!